# Is there a way to build with docker compose without --parallel by default?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to build with `docker compose` without `--parallel` by default?

When I run

```
docker compose build
```

I want it to build containers one by one, but it starts to build all at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Set `COMPOSE_PARALLEL_LIMIT=1` in your env vars, inside `~/.bashrc` for example.

This only affects `docker compose build`, it has nothing to do with `docker compose up`.

Answer (score -2):

You could utilize [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) and chain your services, making them depend on one another.

Comment: The `depends_on` is used for starting or stopping containers in order, but has nothing to do with building. (This statement is true for docker-compose v1 with [legacy compose specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on), but doesn't seem true for docker-compose v2 with [new compose file specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on))